# Error: Model not initialized: "Model" needs to be added t o a Sequelize instance before "call" can be called. (Sequelize-typescript)

Tags: typescript, model, initialization, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Author.ts

```
import {Table, Model, Column, DataType} from 'sequelize-typescript'

@Table
export class Author extends Model<Author> {

constructor(){
    super();
}

@Column(DataType.STRING)
fname: string

@Column(DataType.STRING)
lname: string

}
```

App.ts

```
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { customer } from './model/customer';
import { Author } from './model/Author';

export  class SQLRepo {

     repo:Sequelize = null;

     constructor(){
         this.connectDb();
     }

  connectDb(): any {

    this.repo =  new Sequelize({
        database: 'postgres',
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: 'localhost',
        username: 'postgres',
        password: 'xxxxx',
        storage: 
               'D:/Sequalize/assosiation/database.sqlite',
        modelPaths: [__dirname + '/models'],
        define: {
            underscored: false,
            freezeTableName: false,
            timestamps: false
        }
     });

     this.repo.addModels([Author])

     this.repo.
     authenticate().
     then(function(){
         console.log("database connected ...")

         new Author({fname: 'karim' , lname: 'mirazul'}).save();

     }).
     catch(function(error){
         console.log("Database catch block : "+ error)
     })
   }
}
new SQLRepo();
```

create SQLRepo call object so by this I can connect to database successfully but It shows error after database is connected ..
When it try to insert data into **Author**

it give me this output :

Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
database connected ...
Database catch block :

```
Error: Model not initialized: "Model" needs to be added to
 a Sequelize instance before "call" can be called.
```

Comment: try to drop `modelPaths` from the config option you pass to `new Sequelize`. I think it's redundant and may cause the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Remove constructor call from model

```
import {Table, Model, Column, DataType} from 'sequelize-typescript'

@Table
export class Author extends Model<Author> {

  // constructor(){
  //     super();
  // }

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  fname: string

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  lname: string

}
```

You cannot use constructor as it's used by sequelize for internal things

[source](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/blob/2e466626409a62ef86e9b0aece80625625a35df6/src/model/model/model.ts#L33)

Answer (score -4):

Changing `target: "es5"` to `target: "es6"` helped me solve this issue. It is not documented but it is present in the [example provided](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript-example/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L4).

Comment: Tries this solution and it remains the same issue.